# fill and resize image to screen dimension

Tags: html, css, image, fullscreen

I’m trying to fill a screen with an image, and have the image not distort. I’d like to do it not as a background image. I’d like to do it using css - I’m aware that this is possible but I’m not finding the correct combination of code.

This is an example of what I want the images to do:

http://kentmatheson.com/index-NEWNEW1.html

You can see that the image(s) fill the screen space to the size of either the narrowest or widest dimension depending on screen width, and do not distort the image. This is great but will not work for my current setup because of css img conflicts.

I’ve got a setup that I want to use, here:

http://kentmatheson.com/index-NEWNEW2.html

but I’m unable to find the correct combination of css code to make it respond as I want. If I fill to the height the image distorts, if I fill to the width the image does not fill the screen...

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working. 
Here you go! 
Good luck!

---

HTML

```
<img id="theimg" src="http://interfacelift.com/wallpaper/D7c82ceb/04087_riomaggioreatsunset_3840x2160.jpg">
```

---

CSS

```
#theimg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%!important;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: right;
}
```

Comment: Thats it! Thanks very much.